# Restlet Can't parse payload of a GET request

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am using Restlet in java as a simple client to make calls to a RESTful service provided by tastypie (python django)

I am monitoring the payload through tcpmon and I am seeing the following payload get returned however i can't get at the data in the payload.

**Client calls**

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://localhost/someplace/");
String rep = resource.get(String.class);
```

**Payload**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 20:22:12 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Vary: Cookie
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:  sessionid=63c5ea23113073e489cb8920819f37d; expires=Thu, 26-Jul-2012 20:22:12 GMT;           httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/

{"jsonData": "someData"}
```

When i debug into restlet i notice that the InboundWay.createEntity(..) is setting the data to EmptyRepresentation due to the lack of length, chunkEncoding, or connection headers.  Why is this?  Why can't I just stream the data?

Does any one know why this is happening?  Is there a better client? So far tried jersey and Resteasy with limited success. (jeresy has a bug where it is trying to mark and reset a autoCloseSteam, and resteasy was just a pain to use as a client)  I was hoping not to have to write an HTTPClient.

Did a bit more digging it looks like RESTLET is doing something quite silly in my oppinion.

It is looking a the response headers and trying to find if it knows the size, or if its chunkedEncoding, or if the Connection:closed is specified.  Otherwise it does NOT try to parse the payload ... Does anyone know why this is?  I didn't realize that those headers are required in any way.  Why can't we use the ClosingInputStream when the connection close is not specified...

**Restlet Code**

```
public Representation createInboundEntity(Series<Parameter> headers) {
        Representation result = null;
        long contentLength = HeaderUtils.getContentLength(headers);
        boolean chunkedEncoding = HeaderUtils.isChunkedEncoding(headers);
        // In some cases there is an entity without a content-length header
        boolean connectionClosed = HeaderUtils.isConnectionClose(headers);

        // Create the representation
        if ((contentLength != Representation.UNKNOWN_SIZE && contentLength != 0)
                || chunkedEncoding || connectionClosed) {
            InputStream inboundEntityStream = getInboundEntityStream(
                    contentLength, chunkedEncoding);
            ReadableByteChannel inboundEntityChannel = getInboundEntityChannel(
                    contentLength, chunkedEncoding);
...
```